# 100% height and overflow with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is more of a design practice question than an actual problem but i'm trying to get 100% height on my main content div with the following layout.

[image]

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <!-- Content -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <div class="main-container-wrapper">
                            <h1>Content</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="right-container-wrapper">
                            <h3>Chat</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This code as it stands, the main-container-wrapper only has the height of the content in it (the h1 with content text). I would like the main-container-wrapper to always be 100% of the viewport and scrollable when the content overflows. I find achieving this setting 100vh on the main content wrapper class a little hacky. As it also causes the boxy to be scrollable for some reason.

When using boostrap, how do you go about setting height on divs to 100% when you have all these parent divs with classes like row and columns.

Some guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe should add something like this to your css code (see fiddle below)

```
.col-xs-8{

  background-color:red;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/smlrolland/2dtugmkm/

Comment: Works, but again, this appears to be anti-pattern.